# Laravel 4.2 create a view count on a Post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Actually I need to implement a counter on a post view.
My structure of table `Advertissements` is

```
Id, Title, Descritpion, Content, view_count, visited_date, Ip
```

I tried to use an event but it's not the best practice I think. I don't know where to place my code.

```
public function show($slug) {
    $advert = Advertissement::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $author = $advert->user;

    $socials = Social::all();

    $catAdvert = AdvertCategory::with(['advertissements' => function($query){
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
    }]);

    //Event problem here
    Event::fire('advertissements.view', $advert);

    return View::make('advertissements.show', compact('advert', 'author', 'catAdvert', 'socials'));
}
```

Comment: Did you just write `Event::fire('advertissements.view', $advert);` or there's a logic behind it? You need a listener on the other side

Comment: I read the doc for Events but i just place //Event problem here
    Event::fire('advertissements.view', $advert); Cause no Folder for event in 4.2 laravel. i try to found another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To fire the event

Refer to the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events).

> The Laravel Event class provides a simple observer implementation, allowing you to subscribe and **listen for events** in your application.

In your code you're firing an event that is not registered anywhere.

First, you need to pass data as an array in the firing process:

```
Event::fire('advertissements.view', array($advert));
```

Second, set the listener. It could be anywhere in your executed code, I usually put it in the `app/routes.php` file (others do it in `app/start/global.php` or in a composer autoloaded file...it's up to you):

```php
Event::listen('advertissements.view', function($advert) {
    // Do what you want to handle the event
});
```

*PS: FYI this is the way to handle events in Laravel 4.x, in Laravel 5 it has changed a bit. Taylor has improved the process, adding artisan command to help making and setting events. Have a look to the [Laravel 5 events docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events)*

#### For your counter

Create a model `Counter`

```
class Counter extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'counters';

    public function advertissement()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Advertissement');
    {
}
```

In your `Advertissement` model add

```
public function counter()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Counter');
{
```

In the migration for the `Counter` add an unsigned integer for `advertissement_id` and another unsegned integer for `views`, then in the listener use:

```
Event::listen('advertissements.view', function($advert) {
    $counter = new Counter();
    $counter->views = $advert->counter()->views++;
    $advert->counter()->save($counter);
});
```

Not tested (I don't have a working 4.2 on my machine right now), but should work.

Comment: srry but i really don't understand how with laravel make a counter actuyally for article

Comment: I didn't understand you didn't know how to implement the counter, the question was about events. Anyway I've exended the answer.

Comment: If what you mean with `Advertissement` is actualy an advertisement you could use ajax with a `get` call to a route to increase the counter, without even touching the events, by the way that way should also work as expected.

Comment: Thx  for your help i appreciate.